# Django manage.py localization

Tags: python, django

It is comfortable for somebody to read messages on native language. Is it a good idea to add localization for output of manage.py in Django?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who are you working with. Personally I prefer having output of developer's stuff in english, even though it is not my native language. I think that anyone who is a professional developer has some grasp of english, and the fact is that it is much easier to find potential errors posted in english than in any other language (especially if you'd translate it your way, that sometimes may involve some uncommon expressions etc.). As far as I know Django manage.py does the stuff that only developers might be intrested in, so don't complicate their lives and leave it without localization. But it is my opinion, I think that you should ask your team members about their preferences.

Comment: totally agree. English is the standard universal language in programming, and you never know if you want to sell, opensource, or have foreign coders hack on your code someday. In the case of manage.py, it's intended for programmers or admins, both which should know enough english.

Comment: Don't forget about terminal encodings. Your efforts may be useless if the terminal used doesn't support your localization.